# cant' Drag and Drop for Design Systems

Tags: android-studio

After update the android studio I am enable to use material designing. but I can't user any UI element in drag and drop mode. mouse curse shows in halfly cutted black circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the new version of android studio uses 2 xml files for each layout. One (e.g. content_main.xml) embedded in the other one (Activity_main.xml). you should open the content_*.xml and do the design in it. hope it helps.